# Laravel Route POST Validation access via URL

Tags: laravel, validation, post, get, routes

I have a view :

```
Route::get('albums', 'AlbumsController@index');
```

Inside of that View i have a Modal Form, the action of the form allowed:

```
Route::post('albumsuser', 'AlbumsController@albumsuser');
```

A normal **POST**, how can i validate via routes when i put directly the URL of "albumuser" on the bowser redirect to "albums index" because on the browser that make the request like **"GET"** and show me ***"MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php"*** i want to prevent that, what is the best way?

Regards

Comment: You can just set up a `GET` request to the same url: `Route::get('albumsuser', 'AlbumsController@index');`

Comment: But if i do that I will not be able to send the POST, i get again "MethodNotAllowedHttpException"

Comment: Sorry I get it, it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First you have to get that view, here you are getting one and posting to another route. So please change it looks like this

```
Route::get('albumsuser', 'AlbumsController@index');
Route::post('albumsuser', 'AlbumsController@albumsuser');
```

I hope this will solve your problem.